# What are Dying particles?

Tags: particles, animation-nodes

maybe a simple question,what are Dying Particles? i used animation nodes "particle data" to filter some dying particles,but result is zero,why?thank you! as the screenshot below:

[image]

Comment: May be adding some pictures for "but results are zero" may help the community to understand it in the better way!

Comment: I am sorry for that!

Comment: Ok, what results do you get after putting it on Alive?

Comment: Particles are not supported in Animation Nodes Blender 2.8. So you will always get an empty list. Not sure what dying particles are.

Comment: Thanks Omar Ahmad! this problem has been  fixed in [205bab2](https://github.com/JacquesLucke/animation_nodes/commit/205bab2816a4b1f90e16322cdfe3737429301550),Unborn,Alive,Dead particles  does work correctly,but Dying particles is still empty list,i not sure it is a bug.

Comment: @charis This commit was later reverted, so it no longer works after that commit. I still don't know what Dying particles mean. Sorry.

Comment: @Omar Amad I am sorry!I was confused about "Dying particles",I mean that how to define the "Dying Particle" in blender and what is used for?